# Excel - Unique value based on additional column

Tags: excel, unique

I am trying to use Excel without a macro to achieve a task trivial with a macro.

I want to check over a column and only select unique values from that column, I am using the following function I found online to do this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(list,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(A$2:$A2,list),0)),"")
```

This function works as expected, however I wish to extend this function and I'm not sure how.

Once I find the next unique value using above, I also want to make an additional check from a row in the same column.

As an example, if the next unique value is found in row `3` I want to check if the value in column `B` row `3` is `"Yes"`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Answer (score 0):

Subject to the fact that I don't understand the formula you are happy with (so may not have understood the question) if you have labels in Row1 then in Row2 and copied down:

> =IF(AND(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)=1,B2="Yes"),"Found","")

might suit your purposes.